# Enable force touch lookup in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, trackpad

I would like to enable Force Touch Lookup in Chrome (like on Safari, when you force touch a link it loads a preview). I've read somewhere that Chromium was working on it but when I checked the project's page, it was written that it's available, so I guess it's something to turn on.

My question is, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Force Touch capability hasn't been added to *Chrome*.

This [article from April 2017](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/04/20/chrome-58-for-mac/) details what has been released with version 58 (current at the time of this answer).  It also goes on to say:

> Although beta versions of the browser on the [Canary channel](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) included
>   support for Touch Bar shortcuts on the new MacBook Pro, Google pulled
>   it from subsequent betas as well as from the stable release as it
>   wasn’t ready for prime time yet.

It's important to note that there is a huge distinction between Chrome, [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/), and [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html).

From the [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) page:

> Google Chrome Canary has the newest of the new Chrome features. Be
>   forewarned: it's designed for developers and early adopters, and can
>   sometimes break down completely.

From the [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/) page:

> Chromium is an open-source browser project that aims to build a safer,
>   faster, and more stable way for all users to experience the web. This
>   site contains design documents, architecture overviews, testing
>   information, and more to help you learn to build and work with the
>   Chromium source code.

Chrome is the "production ready" browser from Google.  Chromium is the open source project behind Google Chrome and Canary is the bleeding edge "beta software". It very similar to the relationship of RedHat Linux, CentOS and Fedora.

If you want this functionality, you need to download the respective project and run that browser; it's not something you can enable in the production version.

Answer (score 0):

While this was indeed an issue for a long time, the most recent update to Chrome now brings Force Touch lookup functionality in the same way as does Safari. Please note that my current version of Chrome for macOS is: 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I do (even on Chrome 60) and it still doesn't behave like Safari

Comment: @ferdi_ I'm sorry to hear that. It has been working flawlessly on my machine. Perhaps try reinstalling Chrome just to check? You can see my current version of the software here: 
https://i.imgur.com/HmeCb7Q.png

Comment: @Martin thanks but just to be sure that we are talking about the same thing, when you "force touch" a link on Chrome, it opens a popup with preview (like in Safari) . ?

Comment: @ferdi_ I think we were indeed talking about two different features. The one I was mentioning (and probably works on your machine) is to "Look Up" a word. However, what you were referring to and I misinterpreted is the "Link Preview" feature. 

Link Preview does not work on my machine. There is, however, a feature request thread on the chromium bug tracking site: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=550484

Sorry for the confusion.